# YouTube IFrame API - Set Video ID from data-video-id

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I am loading YouTube's IFrame API after someone clicks a button on my site. It loads in a modal window. On this button, I also have the Video ID in a "data-video-id" attribute. Is there a way to dynamically load the Video ID into the YouTube API instead of statically declaring the Video ID in the API code like below?

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
        height: '1920',
        width: '1080',
videoId: 'GfCPFk8lyhM', <---(how do I make this dynamic?)
        playerVars: {
           modestbranding: 1,
           rel: 0,
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer 2021

Try the below to dynamically set the video id of the youtube player. There seems to be an issue auto-playing youtube videos through this api but hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <style>.buttons { margin-bottom: 10px; }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre id="debug"></pre>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button data-play-youtube-video="GfCPFk8lyhM">
        Play Video 1
      </button>
      <button data-play-youtube-video="LXb3EKWsInQ">
        Play Video 2
      </button>
      <button id="destroy-youtube-player">
        Destroy Player
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script>
      (function () {
        var tag = document.createElement("script");

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;
        var videoId;

        // Creates youtube video player and assigns it into scope
        // so that we can interact with player outside of this function
        function playVideo() {
          player = new YT.Player("player", {
            height: "400",
            width: "320",
            videoId: videoId,
            playerVars: {
              modestbranding: 1,
              rel: 0
            },
            events: {
              onReady: function (event) {
                event.target.playVideo();
              }
            }
          });
        }

        // grab all buttons with the play youtube video data attribute
        var playYoutubeVideoButtons = document.querySelectorAll(
          "[data-play-youtube-video]"
        );

        // attach an event to each button found in the document
        for (var i = 0; i < playYoutubeVideoButtons.length; i++) {
          playYoutubeVideoButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

            // if previous player was initialised, we destroy it
            if (player) {
              player.destroy();
            }

            // set the video id in scope to the video id located on the button
            videoId = this.dataset.playYoutubeVideo;

            // play the video
            playVideo();

            // update debug text
            document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML =
              "Youtube video: " + videoId + " has started playing.";
          });
        }

        // Below is a just hook an event to a button that destroys the youtube player when clicked
        var destroyYoutubePlayer = document.getElementById(
          "destroy-youtube-player"
        );

        destroyYoutubePlayer.addEventListener("click", function () {
          if (player) {
            document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML =
              "Youtube player has been destroyed.";
            return player.destroy();
          }

          document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "Youtube player has not been initialised.";
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Old Answer 2017

Feed it into the function as a parameter like so. I haven't used the API, but here's a quick way of how to make the video id dynamic.

```js
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(videoId) {
    player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
        height: '1920',
        width: '1080',
        videoId: videoId,
        playerVars: {
           modestbranding: 1,
           rel: 0,
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

document.getElementById('btn-video').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var videoId = this.dataset.videoId;
  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(videoId);
  document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = videoID + ' has been submitted';
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-video" data-video-id="GfCPFk8lyhM">Play</button>
<span id="debug"></span>
```

Comment: It doens't seem to work. I am swapping out "value();" for "data-video-id();" since that is where my video ID is on the button.

I am getting a "video is not defined" on that line.

Comment: you need to swap it to `document.getElementById('ipt-video').dataset.videoId`, see updated example.

Comment: I am not loading the YouTube API script until after the button is clicked. Is it possible to still make this work?

Comment: @Brian I have been trying to figure out the exact same thing for two days now and I am starting to think that it may not be possible. It would not be ideal to load a video by default on every page load before the user clicks to view the video, so, I'm still trying to find a way.

Comment: @Envayo I've updated the example, note you'll probably have to use the code locally as Stack Overflow doesn't let you play youtube videos in iframes for security reasons, hope this helps.

Comment: @Win Thanks. But are you sure that it works? I tried a lot but couldn't make it work. Before your comment, I came up with my own solution as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67415313/322417 Seems to be enough for me at the moment. Variable video id and start time are what I needed to pass to the player.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "loadVideoById" function.
The iFrame api has all the functions you need.

[HERE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Queueing_Functions) is the link for you.

This is what you should be using.

Comment: Would this work if the YouTube script doesn't load until after the button is clicked?