# Make onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() work in Ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube-iframe-api

I am getting video data via Ajax from my DB and I need to load the YouTube video in the player in Ajax `success` callback.

Outside Ajax, `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` works fine. But inside Ajax, it does not work. No errors, seems it is not firing.

Here's my whole code:

```
// HTML
<div id="player"></div>

// JS
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player, video;

$('.content').on('click', '.view', function() {
    video = $(this).data('id');
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/scripts/video-view.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {video_id:video},
        success: function(data) {
            window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: '390',
                    width: '640',
                    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                    playerVars: {
                        'modestbranding': 1
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work in Ajax success callback?

P.S. The reason I need it via Ajax is to load videoId and some playerVars dynamically. `videoId` is a static value in the above example for demonstration purpose. In live, it is a dynamic value retreived from the DB. Also, I am testing this on live server, not on localhost.

Comment: Where is your Ajax call?

Comment: @Reyno Added my whole code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found one way to do it. It may not be the best or ideal way, but it seems to do most of what I need it to do.

```
// HTML
<div id="player"></div>

// JS
var player, videoId;

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        playerVars: {
            'fs': 0,
            'modestbranding': 1,
            'playsinline': 1
        }
    });
}

$('.content').on('click', '.view', function() {
    videoId = $(this).data('id');
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/scripts/video-view.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {video_id:videoId},
        success: function(data) {
            player.loadVideoById({'videoId':data.id, 'startSeconds':data.start});
        }
    });
});
```

Ajax returns `data.id` as video id, and `data.start` as video start time. The above setup is enough for dynamic video id and start time, retrieved from the DB. I guess I can live with static playerVars values.

I will not mark this as accepted answer for the time being, in case someone else posts a better solution.